# Freeform "Secure Forms timeout"

Tags: solspace-freeform

We're getting the following error:
"You are not authorized to perform this action - Reason: Secure Forms Timeout"

Every time we submit step 1 of a multi-page form. It was working fine yesterday.
We get the same error if we try to go back from step 2 to step 1, for example.

I'm attaching the form template in an html file.

Can you please help? The form is published and it should be heavily used on a trade show during this weekend! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Way changed between ? Different server, user, computer... if it was and now its not something has to have changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using www.SITE.com but your configs site url is set to 'site.com' or vice versa while also using a www redirect? This is a common error as 'www' is a subdomain and posting to non-www will fire the redirect, which loses all post vars.

Also, are you caching the form? You shouldn't cache forms as they use unique XID hashes for security and once they are used from a single POST, they have to be regenerated.

Answer (score 0):

That feature uses EE's check_xid() method to generate/test a request token. Those tokens are tied to an IP address and a time stamp. They're only good for 120 minutes.

A couple things could go wrong here:

- The form is being cached; so an XID for another visitor is being cached on the form and will never be valid.
- The visitor let the token expire. Pressing the back button will take the person back to the same form with the same expired id and it will fail again if submitted.
- The vistor is coming from Tor or a corporate firewall/proxy where the IP address is changing between requests.

Go have a look at check_xid() in  expressionengine/core/EE_Security.php