# Freeform / EE 2.7 : Reason: Secure Forms Timeout

Tags: solspace-freeform, upgrade

I have a Freeform form running on a site. The form runs at sub.domain.com/folder/index.php and basically uploads a file and sends two emails.

Yesterday, all was working well while under EE 2.6.1. Today I updated EE to 2.7 and now anytime I submit the form I get this message :

> You are not authorized to perform this action - Reason: Secure Forms
>   Timeout

The only thing that change is the EE upgrade. I'm using Freeform 4.0.12.

I did see this [thread](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13138/freeform-secure-forms-timeout) and double checked there was no redirect, but everything happens under the same folder on the same subdomain.

Thanks for any pointer you could provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, Freeform is not compatible with EE2.7 - check the blogpost here http://www.solspace.com/blog/entry/compatibility_with_ee_2.7.0/

Comment: It is now. :) Freeform 4.1.0 was released: http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/change_log/#v4.1.0